# ofstreamFile << ifstreamFile.rdbuf() fails but file text from file is written to ofstreamFile correctly

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream

```
std::ifstream inFile;
std::ofstream outFile;
// ...
outFile << inFile.rdbuf();
```

I was writing one file into another with rdbuf, everything was good. I decided to add error check

```
std::ifstream inFile;
std::ofstream outFile;
// ...
if(!(outFile << inFile.rdbuf()))
// error message
```

And on the same files it started to fail all the time, but the text is copied into the outFile . But if I check

```
std::ifstream inFile;
std::ofstream outFile;
// ...
outFile << inFile.rdbuf();
if (inFil2.bad() || !inFile2.good())
  // error message
```

There is no error message and program runs good, I got my file copied.

**UPDATE:**
outFile.bad() == false, but outFile.fail() == true.

> *failbit is generally set by an operation when the error is related to the internal logic of the operation itself; further operations on the stream may be possible*

I don't really understand what "internal logic of the operation itself" suppose to mean... Maybe somebody can explain?
Is it a way to find out what happened and why failed bit is set, though text seems to be copied correctly from one file to another?

Comment: The output of `operator<<` for `std::ofstream` is `std::ofstream&` not a boolean type.

Comment: @Ghasem Ramezani : istream and ostream overite the bool() operator. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: @ArminMontigny and [`operator!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!), too

Comment: Late to the party, but this is not reproducible.

Comment: In `if (inFil2.bad() || !inFile2.good())`, I suppose you meant `inFile`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why in your case you were getting the `fail()` flag since you said you could see the text copied in the output file (or maybe you did not delete/truncate the file and were seeing old data?)

In any event, today I debugged such an issue in my code and it took me all day to finally understand that the issue I had was that the input file was empty.

The following sets the `fail()` bit of the `outFile` object if `inFile` is empty:

```
outFile << inFile.rdbuf();
```

It may also happen if the file get pointer is at the end (i.e. `inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);` or the file was already read once earlier).

Not only that, once the `fail()` bit is set, the copy of an `rdbuf()` always fails and nothing gets copied. So even if you have a second `inFile2` file and it's not empty, it won't get copied.